# Catching all exceptions and errors in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I've tried to catch all exceptions and errors in PHP in a way so that I can deal with them consistently.

This is the code with the exception of the very last bit where I instead pass `$e` on to a method that outputs an error page as HTML.

```
// Only let PHP report errors in dev
error_reporting(ENV === 'dev' ? E_ALL : 0);

// Register handler
set_error_handler("error_handler");
set_exception_handler("error_handler");
register_shutdown_function("error_handler");

function error_handler()
{
    // Check for unhandled errors (fatal shutdown)
    $e = error_get_last();

    // If none, check function args (error handler)
    if($e === null)
        $e = func_get_args();

    // Return if no error
    if(empty($e))
        return;

    // "Normalize" exceptions (exception handler)
    if($e[0] instanceof Exception)
    {
        call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, array(
            $e[0]->getCode(),
            $e[0]->getMessage(),
            $e[0]->getFile(),
            $e[0]->getLine(),
            $e[0]));
        return;
    }

    // Create with consistent array keys
    $e = array_combine(array('number', 'message', 'file', 'line', 'context'), 
                       array_pad($e, 5, null));

    // Output error page
    var_dump($e);
    exit;
}
```

I'm wondering if this is a decent way of doing it or if I have missed anything crucial. Any comments?

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think that printing raw errors/data to the users is a good idea:

   > ```
   > var_dump($e);
   > ```

   They (usually) can't fix it, so it doesn't help them. ([See #3 here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45075/7076)) It might also contain sensitive information which could help attackers.

   Instead of that you should [log the errors to a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12835262/843804), hide the details from the user (don't forget to print a friendly error message) and fix the errors. Your users might not call/mail you when they found a bug. They just simply use one of your competitor's service.
2. Instead of using the same function for three more or less different purposes:

   > ```
   > set_error_handler("error_handler");
   > set_exception_handler("error_handler");
   > register_shutdown_function("error_handler");
   > ```

   I'd use three different functions (with proper signatures) which might call a fourth one. It would be cleaner (easier to read, understand and maintain). It would make unnecessary the internal magic with `error_get_last()`, `func_get_args()` and `instanceof`.
3. > ```
   > // Only let PHP report errors in dev
   > error_reporting(ENV === 'dev' ? E_ALL : 0);
   > ```

   It seems to me as a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell): [Test Logic in Production](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html). I'd use php.ini to set this, I guess php.ini is a straightforward place for most of the PHP developers to set this instead of a PHP file.