# Am I organising my PHP code effectively?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to learning PHP & MySQL (I've got past experience with Java) and I'm doubting whether my code is organised well. I've got an index page which has two forms; the first is a form to login and the second is a form to sign up a user. So far I've only completed the signing up of a user. Please comment on my code in general and what I can improve.

The form (table tags removed):

```
<form action='php/signup.php' method='post' name='signup'>
    <input name='username' type='text' />
    <input name='password' type='password' />
    <input name='signin' type='submit' value='Sign up' />
</form>
```

signup.php:

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO(...);
    $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    foreach ($db->query("SELECT username FROM usertable") as $row) {
        if ($row == $username) {
            header("Location: http://example.com/#");
            return;
        }
    }
    $user = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
    $user->execute(array(":username" => $_POST["username"], ":password" => $_POST["password"]));
    $db = null;
    header("Location: http://example.com/anotherpage.html");
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo $e -> getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Iterating through the whole user table could be ineffective:

   > ```
   > foreach ($db->query("SELECT username FROM usertable") as $row) {
   > ```

   You could use a `WHERE username LIKE :username` condition here. (And you might need a database index for the attribute as well)
2. The code does not check the password. I guess you should do that.
3. You should [hash your passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36833/4959).
4. Calling a table `usertable` is a little bit redundant. I'd use simply `users`.
5. The following is hard to read because it needs horizontal scanning:

   > ```
   > $user->execute(array(":username" => $_POST["username"], ":password" => $_POST["password"]));
   > ```

   I would introduce an explanatory variable and some line breaks:

   ```
   $newuser_parameters  = array(
       ":username" => $_POST["username"], 
       ":password" => $_POST["password"]
   );
   $user->execute($newuser_parameters);
   ```

   From *Code Complete, 2nd Edition*, p761:

   > **Use only one data declaration per line**
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > It’s easier to find specific variables because you can scan a single
   >   column rather than reading each line. It’s easier to find and fix
   >   syntax errors because the line number the compiler gives you has 
   >   only one declaration on it.

   See also: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods, Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*; *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*.
6. I would validate at least the maximum length of the username.
7. This probably isn't too useful for your clients:

   > ```
   > echo $e -> getMessage();
   > ```

   See #3 in [my former answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45075/7076).

Comment: Regarding #2, #3, #6 and #7, I'm too concerned about them because this is for a basic assignment, though I'll implement all of your suggestions anyway. Regarding #1, I was thinking that my implementation wasn't efficient. Thanks a lot. Oh and regarding #5, I'm too used to pressing CRTL-F in eclipse...

Comment: @Someone: I'm glad that it helped. #5: Autoformat is great, I guess you can configure it.

Comment: Just one minor hint:  You can drop the colons from your user parameter array and it still works fine.  array('username' => ...  Still use the colon in your prepared statement sql.